# IIS7 - combination of ASP.NET customErrors, IIS httpErrors

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, custom-errors

I've seen a number of similar questions to this on StackOverflow and on other sites, but nothing that seems to resolve the issue I'm experiencing.

I'm trying to configure a site to return a 500 status code and a custom error page (static HTML file) for ASP.NET errors that would normally return a 500 where customErrors is set to "Off", and 404 status code for pages that our system reports as not being found (the 404 page is not a static page set via IIS, it's generated by our CMS system).

I'm part way there, but I've hit a bit of a brick wall.

At present, I'm able to return the correct 404 status code where our system returns a page with a 404 status code, but I'm now unable to return a 500 status code for ASP.NET server errors.  I managed this by setting Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true.  My 500 errors, however, are proving more complicated.  If I remove the customErrors config section from my web.config, I get the 500 error but it's the ugly ASP.NET YSOD.  I can't seem to get this to point to a custom page using IIS at all, no matter what settings I use for the httpErrors config section and no matter what I set via the IIS GUI.  If I add the customErrors section back, I get the custom error page as I'd expect, but I get a 200 or 302 error (depending on the value of redirectMode attribute).

Anyone got any ideas?

In terms of httpErrors config section I've tried the following so far:

Setting errorMode to "Custom" and specifying my static content for errors with a statusCode of "500" and a subStatusCode of "-1" (removing existing 500 error first)
Setting errorMode to "Detailed" and specifying my static content for errors with a statusCode of "500" and a subStatusCode of "-1" (removing existing 500 error first)
Setting existingResponse="PassThrough" for both configuration options above.

Comment: I've got the same behaviour across both IIS7.0 and IIS7.5. I'll post the relevant bits from the current web.config in a few hours when I'm back in the office.

Comment: IMHO, for complete the question and the answer with real sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you may be going above and beyond what you need to do, that is if I understand you correctly.  [Here is a good link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994a1482%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

It seems like you what you need is to handle the global.asax `Application_Error` Event.  This way you can handle it anyway you like and you dont get that ugly asp.net error screen.  Any web app I create I put some code in there to handle errors so the user wont see any unformatted "blow ups"

Comment: We're actually running an HttpModule that's already doing stuff in the Application_Error handler for custom logging but we still need to throw the 500 error when there's a major issue as our client uses tools that look for 500 status code to indicate major issues from several sites, so we need to throw them to keep in line, but we don't want end-users seeing a YSOD as we have a perfectly good human readable error page to keep the UX consistent and to keep the details of the underlying error away from prying eyes.

Comment: Are you able to post some of that code?  I have done alot of this type of error handling and it doesnt seem like it shouldn't be this difficult.  Its hard to nail it down w/o some code.